# How do I know if a shortest path from one node to another can be determined when only the shortest path of the graph is shown?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory, shortest-path, dijkstra

I am working on this question and I'm stuck. How do I know whether or not I can determine a shortest path from one node to another when only the shortest path of the whole graph is shown?
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGCRC.png)

I tried drawing a potential full picture of the G and the potential weight of edges that are not in the shortest path of G. I am still stuck.

Comment: Seems like you need to consider what edges you'd need to add to change the shortest path, and then consider whether those edges introduce a contradiction (ie, if they were present, would `T` still be the `SHORTEST PATH TREE from v1`? Example, finding the path from `v3` to `v11`, we could imagine an edge from `7-11` with weight `1`, but that would mean `T` is wrong, so that can't happen. Anyway this is just a quick guess, best of luck.

Comment: " the shortest path of the whole graph"  What does this mean?  Does it mean the minimum spanning tree?  "whether or not I can determine a shortest path from one node to another" What does this mean?  You can find the shortest path by running the Dijkstra algorithm.  What do you mean by 'determine' if you do not mean find?

Answer (score 0):

The shortest path between two vertices cannot be longer than the shortest path through the tree.

The shortest path cannot be so short that it would contradict the tree containing a shortest paths from v1 to everything else.

If those constraints have a gap you can add one edge of the correct length to produce a counterexample.

If those constraints are the same, then the tree already has the shortest path.

I won't give examples because that would be doing your homework.